# Согласие пользователя из ЕС на предоставление личных данных. Пользователи, не достигшие возраста согласия

Tags: android, admob, sdk

В Consent SDK сказано если издателю известно, что пользователь не достиг возраста согласия, все запросы объявлений должны установить TFUA. А как определить возраст?

Comment: спросить пользователя?!